# Is there a way to stop the windows taskbar from overlapping windows?

Tags: windows-10, desktop

If I set the Windows taskbar to auto-hide, then applications realize that they have that extra space and stretch their window a bit to fill the whole screen. However, when I do pull the taskbar up, it overlaps part of the window. This is mainly a problem because if I accidentally bring up the taskbar, it covers things I'm trying to interact with.

Is there a solution to this?

I suppose an easy one would be to implement a delay in the time it takes for the taskbar to appear after bringing your cursor to the edge of the screen, but I'm open to anything.

Comment: This is catch 22. You will of course not see the part that is covered by the taskbar. And what do you think to gain with a delay. At the end it will cover part of the screen.

Answer (score 7):

Restarting the Windows Explorer process from the task manager has always worked for me.

### Step 1

Right click the toolbar and select "Task Manager"

[image: Open task manager]

### Step 2

Right click on Windows Explorer and select "Restart"

[image]

Source: https://nishantrana.me/2021/05/01/fixed-taskbar-overlapping-showing-in-full-screen-in-windows-10/

Comment: This one worked for me.. YES, on windows 11 :o

Answer (score 4):

I really don't know why it happens but you can fix it by only restarting explorer.exe with Task Manager.

Greets

Answer (score 4):

Auto-hiding Taskbar will always overlap over the window. You can often solve the problem by moving the taskbar from bottom edge of the screen to top, left or right edge.

Also, there are solutions with help of keyboard, but they require more specific description of what operation you want to perform (edit your question and describe your task more in detail if you are interested).

Comment: and you can move the taskbar by changing the setting `Lock the taskbar` from on to off.  Then simply left click and drag the taskbar to any far side of the screen and it will snap-to that side.

Answer (score 0):

You see how bad it got from win 7 to win 10 now even worse in win 11 can you only imagine how bad win 12 and 13 will be. I'm definitely going to be looking at moving to Linux operating system in the very near future.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1178882)

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, not a solution for the actual problem, but a really simple trick better than restarting `explorer.exe` is to click once on the windows edge where you hold to resize. It will for a reason jump out of the overlapping.